# How can I filter on different dates based on the value of parameters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In SSRS, is it possible to display different date field results based on a parameter value?
Here is the requirement: There is a parameter called status (values: open, closed, pending) which filters result based on a status field. if open is chosen then all the open loans will display if pending then all the pending loan records will be displayed. Each status has its own date column. In report, user will first select a status (either open, closed or pending), then the date parameter will filter on  date field depending on what is selected. So if user selects open status then date field will filter on open date field. If closed is selected then date filter will filter on closed date and so on. I know cascading parameter functionality will be used but I am really confused on how to allow date filter to filter on a specific status date (based on what status value is chosen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your SQL with a case statement in your WHERE clause.

Something like this:

```
WHERE CASE @statusParam
       WHEN 'open' THEN tbl.open_date
       WHEN 'closed' THEN tbl.close_date
       WHEN 'pending' THEN tbl.pending_date
    END > @startDateParam
```

OR you can do it at the report layer with a [SWITCH()](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ChrisAlbrektson/bidn-blog/1478/ssrs-switch-function-examples) in your filter expression

```
=SWITCH(
    Parameters!statusParam.Value="open", Fields!open_date.Value,
    Parameters!statusParam.Value="closed", Fields!close_date.Value,
    Parameters!statusParam.Value="pending", Fields!pending_date.Value
) > Parameters!startDateParam.Value
```

Doing it in the SQL would be preferred, since it would cut down on the amount of rows returned, unless you need the rest of the dataset for some other part of your report.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have a main dataset with status field and 3 date fields. I have added the SQL query you shared in where clause with ELSE statement(ELSE NULL) because status parameter has a default value of select all so in this else statement if all is selected then date will be null and I have a distinct status dataset that is for status parameter. I need the date parameter to display and filter on current date so I have created a date dataset current date (getdate). Am I doing something wrong? I receive an error that states that there is "," error in my main dataset.

Comment: Try running your query in SQL Server Management Studio. You can emulate the parameters by declaring them as local variables. That should help you track down the problem. Sounds like a typo or a syntax error.

Comment: Actually the reason there was an error was because multi value status parameter, when I took that out it worked fine. I have been trying to work around on hardcoding the "All" option in status parameter but it doesn't return any value. In the case statement I have added when 'All' then productDate(date that always exists). I was hoping this will return all records but nothing is being displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: It would probably be better to ask a separate question for that one. I'm not really sure what you mean and you'll have more space to explain yourself in a new answer. It will also be more beneficial to future visitors that way.